# advanced row deleting in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset, delete-row

I am looking to do row deleting in R based on advanced selection logic (i.e. not just a simple subset). Here is some sample code and what I need to do

```
v1 <- c(1:11)
v2 <- c('a','a','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','c','c')
v3 <- c(3,13,14,13,14,9,14,13,14,13,14)
v4 <- c('','x','','','','x','','','','','x')
v5 <- c('','x','','y','','x','','y','','y','x')

test.df <- data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5)
names(test.df) <- c('id','level','number','end_flag','logic_flag')
```

What I want to do is remove all the rows for each specific level underneath where the first logic flag is equal to 'y'.

So in this case, the end result should remove no rows for level a, rows 5 and 6 for level b, and rows 9,10,11 for level c.

Basically, want to make the first '13' that comes up in the number column for each level the end_flag equal to 'x' and then delete all the rows for that level underneath the end_flag = 'x'
Let me know if this makes sense as I need to clean this part up before proceeding with the rest of my code!

Thanks!

Comment: The statement "Basically, want to make the first '13' that comes up in the number column for each level the end_flag equal to 'x' and then delete all the rows for that level underneath the end_flag = 'x'" in your question confuses. The sample data doesn't seem to follow this (e.g. first '13' under level 'b' doesn't have end_flag equal 'x'). Is this sentence description of your sampole, or of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base `R` using `cumsum` twice:

```
posty <- function(x) cumsum(cumsum(x))<=1
test.df[with(test.df, ave(logic_flag=="y", level, FUN=posty)),]

#  id level number end_flag logic_flag
#1  1     a      3                    
#2  2     a     13        x          x
#3  3     b     14                    
#4  4     b     13                   y
#7  7     c     14                    
#8  8     c     13
```

Comment: works flawlessly thank you! I like that this doesn't require any additional libraries and will therefore accept this answer (although the dplyr solution works perfectly as well and probably easier to explain!)

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` you can do

```
library(dplyr)
test.df %>% group_by(level) %>%
  filter(head(cumsum(c(F, logic_flag == 'y')) == 0, -1))
#   id level number end_flag logic_flag
# 1  1     a      3                    
# 2  2     a     13        x          x
# 3  3     b     14                    
# 4  4     b     13                   y
# 5  7     c     14                    
# 6  8     c     13                   y
```

First, group by level, then remove rows where we have already seen a "y" (using `cumsum`).  An `F` is appended to the `cumsum` vector because we want to include the first row that contains a "y".  Since the length of the vector was increased by 1, `head(..., -1)` is used to drop the last element.  I think `dplyr` has some `lag` functions that could do a similar thing as well.

Comment: If you want to use `lag`: `test.df %>% group_by(level) %>% filter(!lag(cumsum(logic_flag=="y")>0L,1,F))`

Comment: @PierreLafortune nice

Comment: awesome stuff thank you for the explanation as well this worked perfectly! i knew there had to be some way in dplyr to get this working and cumsum is def the trick! ran this on the real data and it only took ~5 seconds on 1.8M rows!